# 4 Minute Delay Between New User Registration and Receipt of Activation Email

Tags: php, mysql, email

I am using a PHP/MySQL login script that sends a new user an activation email.  When a new user registers, the info is put into MySQL pretty much instantly, but then it takes about 4 minutes for the activation email to arrive in the new user's inbox.

It seems like sites like Facebook and Twitter can get out an activation email instantly when a new user registers.  Is there anything that I could do to make the activation email that I'm using arrive instantly or really fast?

Thanks in advance,

John

Answer (score 3):

This really depends on the mail servers between your web host and user's inbox. There can be intentional delays (e.g. [greylisting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greylisting)) set up, and possibly applied only to less trustworthy host (e.g. not Facebook/Twitter). You might want to check you mailserver settings and make sure you have all the server addresses, hostnames and reverse DNS set up correctly.

Comment: Is there any way to get off the grey list?